# C# What are implications of NuGet warning: Package x was restored using NET Framework version

Tags: c#, .net, versioning, .net-framework-version

I do know that this warning means that the package is not compatible with my project's version. In my case it's NET3.1, and the package requires NET Framework at least 4.6.1. I would change target of my project to NET Framework but I need interface default implementations which seem to not work in NET Framework.

But anyway my question is: If all used functions of the package seem to work fine and I ignore these warnings, then release my application, would it mean that my app is fully functional but just needs "both" .NET3.1 and NET Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use .NETCore runtime or .NET Framework runtime. For interop between the two there is .NET Standard which can be used by both runtimes.

I would personally by no means release an application ignoring this warning.